# How do I find out what process has a lock on a file in Linux?

Tags: linux, file, filesystems, directory

Today I had the problem that I couldn't delete a folder because "it was busy".

How can I find out which application to blame for that or can I just delete it with brute force?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use lsof to find out what has what files are open.

man lsof or have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof)

Answer (score 10):

The [`fuser`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuser_(Unix)) Unix command will give you the PIDs of the processes accessing a file.

Answer (score 6):

`lslocks` lists information about all the currently held file locks in a Linux system. (part of util-linux) this utility has support for json output, which is nice for scripts.

```sh
~$ sudo lslocks
COMMAND           PID   TYPE SIZE MODE  M START END PATH
cron              873  FLOCK   4B WRITE 0     0   0 /run/crond.pid

..
..
```

Answer (score 2):

`fuser` will show you which processes are accessing a file or directory.